# python regex to omit complicated referencing style from text

Tags: python, regex

I have read the contents of a file into python and I want to get rid of all of the references which follow the same general format:

```
(Author et al., .............. \nGoogle Scholar) # there could be many '\nGoogle Scholar's within the brackets
```

> Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of
>   Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose
>   perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting
>   beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular
>   variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with
>   specialized tasks and physiological responses (Gutierrez etal.,
>   2017Gutierrez G.D. Gromada J. Sussel L. Heterogeneity of the
>   pancreatic beta cell.Front. Genet. 2017; 8: 22Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus
>   (11)\nGoogle Scholar, Roscioni etal., 2016Roscioni S.S. Migliorini A.
>   Gegg M. Lickert H. Impact of islet architecture on -cell
>   heterogeneity, plasticity and function.Nat. Rev. Endocrinol. 2016; 12:
>   695-709Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (36)\nGoogle Scholar). Features of
>   beta cell heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory
>   activity ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has
>   been infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as
>   photoswitchable dyes (Cui etal., 2018Cui Y. Hu D. Markillie L.M.
>   Chrisler W.B. Gaffrey M.J. Ansong C. Sussel L. Orr G. Fluctuation
>   localization imaging-based fluorescence insitu hybridization (fliFISH)
>   for accurate detection and counting of RNA copies in single
>   cells.Nucleic Acids Res. 2018; 46: e7Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus
>   (2)\nGoogle Scholar). We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH
>   protocol (Lyubimova etal., 2013Lyubimova A. Itzkovitz S. Junker J.P.
>   Fan Z.P. Wu X. van Oudenaarden A. Single-molecule mRNA detection and
>   counting in mammalian tissue.Nat. Protoc. 2013; 8:
>   1743-1758Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (62)\nGoogle Scholar) by
>   substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation, which
>   precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least 3hr.

Desired output

> Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of
>   Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose
>   perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting
>   beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular
>   variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with
>   specialized tasks and physiological responses . Features of beta cell
>   heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity
>   ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been
>   infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as
>   photoswitchable dyes . We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH
>   protocol  by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation,
>   which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least
>   3hr.

I cannot find a regular expression which omits all of the references in one go and so I have had to do this in 2 parts:

1. Find all location of each '\nGoogle Scholar)' occurrence.
2. From each location extend backwards until the corresponding opening bracket occurs and then omit the characters between these indexes.

I attempt this as follows:

```
def remove(test_str):
        regex=re.compile('\\nGoogle Scholar\)')
        starts=[]
        ends=[]
        ret=''
        for end in regex.finditer(test_str): #find all 'Google Scholar)'
            ends.append(m.end())
        for e in ends:                       #find all starting brackets
            i=e
            while True:
                if bool(re.match('\(\D+',test_str[i-2:i])):
                    starts.append(i-2)
                    break
                else:
                    i-=1
        start=test_str[:starts[0]]           #omit all characters in between
        starts=starts[1:]
        end=test_str[ends[-1]:]
        ends=ends[:-1]
        for i,j in zip(starts,ends):
            ret=ret+test_str[j:i]
        return start+ret+end
```

However this strategy fails as the regex that I am using to find each starting bracket (`\(\D+`) is not exact enough- often there are closed brackets within the references e.g.

> (Cui etal., 2018Cui Y. Hu D. Markillie L.M. Chrisler W.B. Gaffrey M.J.
>   Ansong C. Sussel L. Orr G. Fluctuation localization imaging-based
>   fluorescence insitu hybridization **(fliFISH)** for accurate detection and
>   counting of RNA copies in single cells.Nucleic Acids Res. 2018; 46:
>   e7Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (2)\nGoogle Scholar)

Hence in this case the search for the correct opening bracket stops prematurely....

Can anyone recommend a good way of consistently removing all references?

Comment: i have seen that all references end with `'\\nGoogle Scholar\\)' and start with **(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your described pattern, you can use this regex,

```
(?s)\(.*?Google Scholar\) ?
```

And replace it with empty string. Here `(?s)` is for enabling `.` to match new lines.

**[Check here](https://regex101.com/r/j3HvoB/2)**

Here is a python code demo,

```
import re

s = 'Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with specialized tasks and physiological responses (Gutierrez etal., 2017Gutierrez G.D. Gromada J. Sussel L. Heterogeneity of the pancreatic beta cell.Front. Genet. 2017; 8: 22Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (11)\nGoogle Scholar, Roscioni etal., 2016Roscioni S.S. Migliorini A. Gegg M. Lickert H. Impact of islet architecture on -cell heterogeneity, plasticity and function.Nat. Rev. Endocrinol. 2016; 12: 695-709Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (36)\nGoogle Scholar). Features of beta cell heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as photoswitchable dyes (Cui etal., 2018Cui Y. Hu D. Markillie L.M. Chrisler W.B. Gaffrey M.J. Ansong C. Sussel L. Orr G. Fluctuation localization imaging-based fluorescence insitu hybridization (fliFISH) for accurate detection and counting of RNA copies in single cells.Nucleic Acids Res. 2018; 46: e7Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (2)\nGoogle Scholar). We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH protocol (Lyubimova etal., 2013Lyubimova A. Itzkovitz S. Junker J.P. Fan Z.P. Wu X. van Oudenaarden A. Single-molecule mRNA detection and counting in mammalian tissue.Nat. Protoc. 2013; 8: 1743-1758Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (62)\nGoogle Scholar) by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation, which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least 3hr.'

replacedStr = re.sub(r'(?s)\(.*?Google Scholar\) ?','',s)
print(replacedStr)
```

Prints the following like you mentioned in your post.

> Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of
>   Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose
>   perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting
>   beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular
>   variations, suggesting that they may consist of  sub-populations with
>   specialized tasks and physiological responses . Features of beta cell
>   heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity
>   ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been
>   infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as
>   photoswitchable dyes . We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH
>   protocol by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation,
>   which precedes the probehybridization steps, from 5min to at least
>   3hr.

Comment: has multiple spaces in the result which are not present in the desired output

Comment: @SimonF: Can you tell me where there are multiple spaces in my output vs OP's expected output? There was JUST ONE extra space which was just after `smFISH protocol` because that sentence didn't end normally with a dot like others and that's most likely a typo from OP's end. And I can even take care that but it would just make the regex a little unreadable.

Comment: an extra space next to another space equals multiple spaces. I just pointed out a flaw in your solution that could invalidate it depending on how accurate output xenopus wants. I think you are making some assumptions about the question that you shouldn't. And I think a regex that solves a problem is better than an beautiful one that doesn't...

Comment: @SimonF: I've taken care of that extra space too and updated my post and now the output is exactly identical to what OP expected.

Comment: Well done! Did you also consider what happens if there are parentheses in the text?

Comment: @SimonF: Thanks. For parenthesis inside data to be removed, current behavior is it can include parenthesis within that text block, although OP's post doesn't have any. Now depending upon what OP wants, it can be easily done by restricting them with a negated character class. But unless OP shows more data and tells what behavior he wants, refining regex further may not be that useful.

Comment: If there are parentheses in the the ”wanted” text block your code will remove everything from that part until it reaches a reference block. Thus your code assumes that there will not be any parantheses except the ones in the references. I make no such assumptions

Comment: @SimonF: OP has clearly mentioned that he wants to remove everything starting from `(` parenthesis till he sees `Google Scholar)` and my solution exactly does that. Why would you implement something else that OP doesn't want? How can you assume he doesn't want parenthesis or wants parenthesis and go for one particular solution? So unless he says something, your solution should be generic and not restrictive.

Comment: The author asks for a way to remove the references, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it the following way, which matches what you wanted to the letter and can handle parentheses in the text (that are not the references):

1. Look for beginning `\(`
2. Look for a repetition of `[^()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?`, which is one or more characters that are not parentheses followed by an optional pair of `( )` with one or more characters that are not parentheses inside them.
3. Look for ending `\nGoogle Scholar\)`
4. Split and join with spaces to remove multiple spaces

Code:

```
import re
text = 'Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with specialized tasks and physiological responses (Gutierrez etal., 2017Gutierrez G.D. Gromada J. Sussel L. Heterogeneity of the pancreatic beta cell.Front. Genet. 2017; 8: 22Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (11)\nGoogle Scholar, Roscioni etal., 2016Roscioni S.S. Migliorini A. Gegg M. Lickert H. Impact of islet architecture on -cell heterogeneity, plasticity and function.Nat. Rev. Endocrinol. 2016; 12: 695-709Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (36)\nGoogle Scholar). Features of beta cell heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as photoswitchable dyes (Cui etal., 2018Cui Y. Hu D. Markillie L.M. Chrisler W.B. Gaffrey M.J. Ansong C. Sussel L. Orr G. Fluctuation localization imaging-based fluorescence insitu hybridization (fliFISH) for accurate detection and counting of RNA copies in single cells.Nucleic Acids Res. 2018; 46: e7Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (2)\nGoogle Scholar). We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH protocol (Lyubimova etal., 2013Lyubimova A. Itzkovitz S. Junker J.P. Fan Z.P. Wu X. van Oudenaarden A. Single-molecule mRNA detection and counting in mammalian tissue.Nat. Protoc. 2013; 8: 1743-1758Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (62)\nGoogle Scholar) by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation, which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least 3hr.'
fixed_text = ' '.join(re.sub(r'\((?:[^()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)+\nGoogle Scholar\)', '', text).split())
print(fixed_text)
```

Output:

> Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of
>   Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose
>   perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting
>   beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular
>   variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with
>   specialized tasks and physiological responses . Features of beta cell
>   heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity
>   ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been
>   infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as
>   photoswitchable dyes . We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH
>   protocol by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation,
>   which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least
>   3hr.

An improvement can be made by changing to the following code which also removes spaces before the leading `\(`, but then it doesn't match your wanted output (which has the flaw):

```
fixed_text = re.sub(r' ?\((?:[^()]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)+\nGoogle Scholar\)', '', string)
```

> Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of
>   Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose
>   perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting
>   beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular
>   variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with
>   specialized tasks and physiological responses. Features of beta cell
>   heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity
>   ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been
>   infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as
>   photoswitchable dyes. We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH
>   protocol by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation,
>   which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least
>   3hr.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source = """Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with specialized tasks and physiological responses (Gutierrez etal., 2017Gutierrez G.D. Gromada J. Sussel L. Heterogeneity of the pancreatic beta cell.Front. Genet. 2017; 8: 22Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (11)\nGoogle Scholar, Roscioni etal., 2016Roscioni S.S. Migliorini A. Gegg M. Lickert H. Impact of islet architecture on -cell heterogeneity, plasticity and function.Nat. Rev. Endocrinol. 2016; 12: 695-709Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (36)\nGoogle Scholar). Features of beta cell heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as photoswitchable dyes (Cui etal., 2018Cui Y. Hu D. Markillie L.M. Chrisler W.B. Gaffrey M.J. Ansong C. Sussel L. Orr G. Fluctuation localization imaging-based fluorescence insitu hybridization (fliFISH) for accurate detection and counting of RNA copies in single cells.Nucleic Acids Res. 2018; 46: e7Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (2)\nGoogle Scholar). We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH protocol (Lyubimova etal., 2013Lyubimova A. Itzkovitz S. Junker J.P. Fan Z.P. Wu X. van Oudenaarden A. Single-molecule mRNA detection and counting in mammalian tissue.Nat. Protoc. 2013; 8: 1743-1758Crossref\nPubMed\nScopus (62)\nGoogle Scholar) by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation, which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least 3hr."""
    output = re.sub(' \(.*? etal\., .*?\\nGoogle Scholar\)', '', source, flags=re.DOTALL)

    print(output)
```

### output

```
Introduction The endocrine cells in the pancreatic islets of Langerhans secrete insulin and glucagon in response to glucose perturbations to maintain glucose homeostasis. The insulin-secreting beta cells exhibit morphological, functional, and molecular variations, suggesting that they may consist of sub-populations with specialized tasks and physiological responses. Features of beta cell heterogeneity include glucose responsiveness and secretory activity ..... Visualizing transcripts in the pancreas, however, has been infeasible without the use of specialized techniques such as photoswitchable dyes. We have optimized the standard tissue smFISH protocol by substantially increasing the period of mRNA denaturation, which precedes the probe hybridization steps, from 5min to at least 3hr.
```